# Show that a vector space $V$ can only admit a dual if it is finite dimensional.

Tags: linear-algebra, category-theory, monoidal-categories

Let $V$ be an object in the category (Vect$_{\mathbb{C}},\otimes,\mathbb{C}$), and let $\{ e_i\}$ be a basis for $V$. I need to show that if $V$ admits a dual $V^*$ then $V$ must be finite dimensional. I have been given the hint that I must show that the coevaluation is necessarily of this form:
$$1 \mapsto \sum_{i,j}c_{i,j}e_i \otimes e^j,$$ where $c_{i,j} \in \mathbb{C}$ and $\{ e^{j}\}$ is a basis for $V^*$, but I don't know how to show this or why this will be sufficient. Help with the proof or some kind of explanation would be great!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is a 'categorical dual'?

Comment: Ah, I just mean a dual object! Which is a dual vector space in this case.

Comment: Is there some hypothesis I’m missing? Every vector space has a corresponding dual space.

Comment: I think you still need to be more explicit about your definition of "dual", because the [definition of a dual in a symmetric monoidal category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_object) only coincides with $Hom(V,\mathbb{C})$ for finite-dimensional vector spaces, whereas the algebraic dual defined by $Hom$ exists for every vector space.

Comment: The fact that the coevaluation must have that form is totally trivial: $\sum_{i,j}c_{i,j}e_i \otimes e^j$ is simply the general form of an arbitrary element of $V\otimes V^*$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the coevaluation takes this form because $e_i\otimes e^j$ is a basis for $V\otimes V^*$, so it's just the expression of the coevaluation in terms of this basis.

As for why this answers the question, observe that the sum is necessarily finite.

I.e., only finitely many $c_{ij}\ne 0$.

Then the fact that $$V\to k\otimes V\to V\otimes V^*\otimes V\to V\otimes k \to V$$ is supposed to be the identity will be a problem.

Since finitely many $c_{ij}$ are nonzero, there are only finitely many indices $i$ such that $c_{ij}$ is nonzero. Suppose $k$ is such that $c_{kj}=0$ for all $j$.

Then $$e_k \mapsto 1\otimes e_k \mapsto \sum_{i,j} c_{ij}e_i\otimes e^j\otimes e_k \mapsto \sum_{i,j} c_{ij}d_{jk}e_i,$$
where $d_{jk}= \epsilon(e^j\otimes e_k)$ and $\epsilon$ is the evaluation.
Then the coefficient of $e_k$ in this last term is $\sum_j c_{kj} d_{jk} = 0\ne 1$.