# Proving that a Vectorspace has a dual (in the sense of categories) iff it is finite dimensional

Tags: linear-algebra, convergence-divergence, category-theory

This refers to the question (and answer from here: [Show that a vector space $V$ can only admit a dual if it is finite dimensional.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3239120/show-that-a-vector-space-v-can-only-admit-a-dual-if-it-is-finite-dimensional))

I don't know the appropriate procedure here, whether I should ask in the previous thread or a separate question but anyways:

The proof in the answer hinges on the fact that coev$_V(1)=\sum c_{ij}e_i\otimes e^j$ the sum must include only finite amount of terms. But I don't understand why.

Suppose I had coefficients which just go to 0 sufficiently quickly, woudn't this expression be well defined then? This requires of course ev to "blow up".

Example: $\sum c_{ij}e_i\otimes e^j$ with $c_{ij}=\delta_{ij}1/i^2$ in the standard norm induced by the standard inner product. Then ev$(e^j\otimes e_l)=l^2 \delta_{lj}$.

Isn't this ok? Or is ev in such a way not well defined anymore? If so, why?